# How to Texture a Pie Shape with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to texture a pie shape using Qt (5.5) and QPainter. My problem is that the image does not wrap around the pie arc as desired but instead fills the background as if the pie is used as a cookie cutter. I need the bottom left and right corners of the image at the centre of the circle while the top left and right should map to the outer start and end of the pie.

For example, if the image was a black background with a white horizontal line in the middle then the white line would become an arc.

I can't see how this can be achieved in the Qt documentation or if it's possible. I can do the same using OpenGL but I'm looking to simplify the code using QPainter, if possible.

```
QImage image (...);
QBrush imageBrush (image);
painter->setBrush(imageBrush);

QRectF rect (0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
painter->drawPie(rect, 30.0 * 16, 120.0 * 16);
```

[Current pie from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLgXI.png). The lines instead of being horizontal should match the curve of the arc.

Comment: Can't you provide a screenshot of what you have now?

Comment: QPainter is not as mighty as OpenGL. `QBrush::setTransform` could possibly help.